# What is the difference between linkset and linkmap?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

I want to know what is the basic difference between linkset and linkmap in oreintDB ?
And where we will use linkset and where we can use linkmap ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A Link Set is

- A `Set` (An unordered Collection of items, with no duplicates), see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)
- where the items are links to other OrientDB Records (so an item is a single link)

A Link Map is

- A `Map` maps (associates) an `String` key to a link. A `Map` does not accept duplicate Strings, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). OrientDB restricts the type of a key to `String`.

For details, see [OrientDB Documentation about supported Types](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Types.html)

Note that these types are typically used in the context of a Document Database, not a Graph Database (then `RelationShip`s or `Edge`s are used)

Comment: Is the key the string version of the rid or some? Does this means the removal, search of rids in a linkmap is instant?

Comment: @Michael Post this as a separate question, should not be answered in the comments of another question