# How to choose between Links and Edges to connect vertices?

Tags: orientdb

In orientDB, we have links and edges to connect vertices.
I can't find out what the cons/pros of each of them on the orientdb documentation.

Forum Example - three entities involved: Author, Message, Forum.

An author writes a message in a forum.
- Option one: message is an edge between Author and Forum vertices
- Option two: Message has a link to Author and another link to Forum

In other words, what strategy to choose and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have properties on your arch you can use a link, instead if you have it use edges.

Comment: Thanks! Actually i'd like to know if the performances are the same. in other words, are all the edges automatically loaded when the involved vertices are loaded? is it the same for linklist?

Comment: Another related issue: any Edge can be converted to a Link (or link list) to another Vertex. So is it worth having edges at all? if the answer is no then when to use links and when we really need edges?

Comment: You really need edges if you need to traverse the ralationship in both directions, while using the linklist you can only in one direction.

Answer (score 12):

***Edges*** are all about connecting *vertices*.
**Links** are all about relations between other **classes**.

Two **classes** may not be associated at all, like a `class` **Oceans** and a `class` **Person**. But you can have their *vertices* associated by an ***Edge*** named ***Sailed*** that may have a property named ***withShipName`***.

So you made a **Person** vertex called *Jack Sparrow*, and a **Ocean** vertex named *Atlantic*. Then you create an their edge relationship ***sailed*** which you can connect like:

*Jack Sparrow* ***sailed.withShipName= Black Pearl*** the *Atlantic*.

But if you have another **Person** vertex, like *Red riding hood*, you don't want to have a **link** in their vertex properties relating her with an **Ocean** `class`.

However, you may want to have a *linklist* or *linkmap* linking the `class` **Ocean** with `class` **OpticalActiveWaterConstituents**, that have vertices to *Chorophyll*, *Suspended Particles*, *Coloured Dissolved Organic Matter*, etc... that are available in all Oceans with different concentrations.

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31167937/5013735) for the differences between ***Edges*** vs **LinkList** vs **Linkmap**.

Hope this help to clarify the subject ;)